# change legend symbols from boxplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am plotting a series of boxplots as well as points on top but my color legend shows all the symbols as little boxes. I've tried using override.aes but the problem persists. Bonus points if you can show me how to make r^2 appear nicely in the title.

```
r2df.realtime=subset(r2df,yr>reconyear)
r2df.sameyr=subset(r2df,yr==reconyear)
ggplot()+geom_boxplot(data=r2df.realtime,aes(as.factor(yr),r2phvrcn,col='model1'),outlier.shape=3)+
    geom_boxplot(data=r2df,aes(x=as.factor(yr),y=r2phv,col='model2'))+
    geom_point(data=r2df,aes(x=as.factor(yr),y=r2recon,col='model3'),shape=6)+
    geom_point(data=r2df.sameyr,aes(x=as.factor(yr),y=r2phvrcn,col='model4'),shape=6)+
    scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red','green','black'))+
    facet_grid(~mth)+
    guides(color=guide_legend('Model'),override.aes=list(shape=c(6,6,1,1)))
    labs(title=paste('Real-time Ensemble of Cross-Validated Skill Scores (',expression(r^2),')',sep=''))
```

[link to text file with dput(r2df)](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5962491/r2df.txt)

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to what is necessary to show the problem?

Comment: it's the complexity that is the problem.... but i've removed some of the axis labels and such. what else is not clear?

Answer (score 0):

First, to remove boxplot "shapes" from the legend you should add `show_guide=FALSE` to two `geom_boxplot()` calls. Then yo change shapes in legend with `override.aes=` you should place it inside `guide_legend()` (in your try it was placed as separate argument inside function `guides()`).

Second, in your title call change order of functions `paste()` and `expression()`.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_boxplot(data=r2df.realtime,aes(as.factor(yr),r2phvrcn,col='model1'),
                                           outlier.shape=3,show_guide=FALSE)+
  geom_boxplot(data=r2df,aes(x=as.factor(yr),y=r2phv,col='model2'),show_guide=FALSE)+
  geom_point(data=r2df,aes(x=as.factor(yr),y=r2recon,col='model3'),shape=6)+
  geom_point(data=r2df.sameyr,aes(x=as.factor(yr),y=r2phvrcn,col='model4'),shape=6)+
  scale_color_manual(values=c('blue','red','green','black'))+
  facet_grid(~mth)+
  guides(color=guide_legend('Model',override.aes=list(shape=c(1,1,6,6))))+
  labs(title=expression(paste("Real-time Ensemble of Cross-Validated Skill Scores 
                                                                (",r^2,")",sep='')))
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't quite get me what I'm looking for. I would still like to keep the boxplot shape for 'model1'. I would  like to display a line for 'model2', and triangles for 'model3' and 'model4'. `show_guide=T` for 'model1' causes all shapes to be boxplots. I tried using geom_segment instead of geom_boxplot for model2 but couldn't get it to work.  The output on the graph is the same because there is only one value for model2.